# Mixing of two strings giving undesired output

Tags: java, string

I was just experimenting with the fusion of the strings in Java (I don't know what we call them so I'm saying fusion)

```
int sum = 11+13;
int sum2 = 12+4;
```

So then I started to print them with different fusion of strings like:

```
System.out.println(  "Answer is " + sum + sum2 );  //Answer is 2416
System.out.println(  "Answer is " + sum + ' ' + sum2  );  //Answer is 24 16
System.out.println(  "Answer is " + (sum+sum2)  );  //Answer is 40
System.out.println(  "Answer is " + (sum + ' ' + sum2)  );  //Answer is 24 16
```

It worked fine with the 1st, 2nd and 3rd statements. But in the 4, it's output was

> Answer is 72

But why is it coming? I thought the output should be

> Answer is 24 16

as first we are outputting the string "Answer is " and then we are outputting this- (sum + ' ' + sum2) and as there is a string between the sum and sum 2, they shall become a string too. But instead it's giving the output 72.
Also, I'm using IntelliJ to run this programm if it will help.
One last thing, this works perfectly fine if I replace the ' ' with " ", but why? It works fine with the 2nd statement.

Comment: `' '` is __not__ a String. Its a character, which basically is a number.

Comment: @tkausl Ya I know, but it runs perfectly fine in statement 2, while in statement 2 also it was a character

Comment: @Gon49 yes, but in statement 4 you're working in a numerical context because of the parentheses. You're summing an `int`, a `char` and another `int`, which means you're dealing only with numbers.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Sorry but I did'nt understood what you said

Comment: @Gon49 because of the parentheses `(sum + ' ' + sum2)` is evaluated on its own, then it's concatenated. The fact that it's evaluated on its own means that since `sum`, `' '` and `sum2` are all numerical (because, as you know, a `char` is a number) first it calculates that number. Then, and just then, it sees the rest of the rest of the expression, which is asked to do a `+` operation between a string (`"Answer is "`) and the number calculated in the inner expression, which results in a string.

Comment: Thanks @FedericoklezCulloca I understood it well now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `' '` in `(sum + ' ' + sum2)` is considered as a character code which is 32.

```
    int b = ' ';
    System.out.println(  "Answer is " + b  );  //Answer is 32
```

So, 24 + 32 + 16 = **72**

Comment: So you mean that the value of ' ' is 32 ?

Comment: Yep, you can check ASCII code here https://www.ascii-code.com/, you can look at the line 32, you'll the symbol ' ' :)

Answer (score 2):

Because ' '(space)is char, not String, and char is used in operations with int, often using ascii code, the ascii code of ' '(space) is 32, so 24 + 32 + 16 = 72. When you use System.out.println( "Answer is "+ (sum +" "+ sum2) ), you will get the answer "Answer is 24 16"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the already provided answers: The difference here is that when the subexpression `x + ' '` is evaluated in the second case the `x` is of type `String`, while in the fourth case it is of type `int`. So in the second case the `+` means string concatenation, while in the fourth it is addition.

Answer (score 0):

Parantheses + ASCII code gives the 72.

Parantheses makes the integers sum up. You're assuming that output should be 24 16 but within paranthese the values are not strings. sum and sum2 are int. So, all the values are added. As explained by others, space holds a value of 32. This ensures, that the output is 72.

**Note**: If you want to get 24 16, you'd have to use ***String.valueOf()***.

```
System.out.println("Answer is " + (String.valueOf(sum) + ' ' + String.valueOf(sum2)) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything enclosed inside `''` is considered as a character literal. The character literal `space` is dec `32`.

On the other hand statement inside `()` is evaluated as an addition operation with values considered as `24 + 32 + 16`, hence you get an answer as `72`.

Similarly `(sum + '!' + sum2)` would have produced `73`.